# How can get the first 4 char column 1 that is exact match to column 2 in sql

Tags: sql, database

Question 4
First, create a list of all the contact people where the first 4 characters of their last name are equal to the first 4 characters of their email address.
Second find all the contact people whose first name and the last name begin with the same character, create a new column called full name combining their first name and their last name. Finally, add a column with the length of the full name.

Comment: And where are you stuck? And what have you tried? And what DBMS do you use?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions. Note that homework related questions are expected to prove some extra effort.

Comment: look up the functions LEFT and SUBSTRING depending the the DBMS you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the first characters of a string in SQL Server use the built in function:

```
LEFT(yourColumn, numberOfCharacters)
```

Example:

```
LEFT(usrEmail, 4)
```

To get the length of a string, use the built in function:

```
LEN(yourString)
```

Example:

```
LEN(usrForename + usrSurname)
```

And to declare a new column just use 'AS' in your select.
Example:

```
SELECT 
usrForename + ' ' + usrSurname AS FullName
```